# AWS SDK installation problem

Tags: drush

I used Drush to install Amazon S3 module. AWS SDK was installed as part of the process. No error was thrown

```
[root@ip-10-128-146-179 zencoder]# drush dl amazons3
Project amazons3 (7.x-1.0-beta7) downloaded to                         [success]
/var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/amazons3.
[root@ip-10-128-146-179 zencoder]# drush en amazons3
The following projects have unmet dependencies:
amazons3 requires awssdk
Would you like to download them? (y/n): y
Project awssdk (7.x-5.4) downloaded to                                 [success]
/var/www/html/drupal/sites/all/modules/awssdk.
Project awssdk contains 2 modules: awssdk_ui, awssdk.
The following extensions will be enabled: amazons3, awssdk
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
amazons3 was enabled successfully.                                     [ok]
awssdk was enabled successfully.                                       [ok]
```

Now I see an error in my Drupal admin dashboard:

```
Failed to load the AWSSDK
Please make sure the AWSSDK library is installed in the libraries directory. Use the drush make file for easy installation.
```

What shoud I do?

This is my drush status:

```
Drupal version                  :  7.22                 
 Site URI                        :  http://default       
 Database driver                 :  mysql                
 Database hostname               :  localhost            
 Database username               :  drupal               
 Database name                   :  drupal               
 Database                        :  Connected            
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful           
 Drupal user                     :  Anonymous            
 Default theme                   :  bartik               
 Administration theme            :  seven                
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/php.ini         
 Drush version                   :  5.9                  
 Drush configuration             :                       
 Drupal root                     :  /var/www/html/drupal 
 Site path                       :  sites/default        
 File directory path             :  sites/default/files  
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the AWS PHP SDK version 1.6.2 instead of the latest solved the problem. `sites/all/libraries/awssdk/sdk.class.php` does not apply for at least version 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the [AWSSDK library](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) and extract it to your sites/all/libraries folder following the format **sites/all/libraries/awssdk/sdk.class.php.**

Comment: sites/all/libraries/awssdk/sdk.class.php does not exist for the latest version of AWS SDK for PHP. So I had to use version 1.6.2

Comment: version 2.0 wasn't out when release 5.4 was created. So yes you were supposed to use version 1.6. My guess is it now works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this command from the Drupal root after installing the awssdk module and it worked:

drush make --no-core sites/all/modules/awssdk/awssdk.make

By worked, I mean it set up the library and fixed the "Failed to load the AWSSDK" error.

The command is referenced here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1353114#comment-5300564